# How to read in multiple ".xlsx" files to R

Tags: r, xlsx

Having trouble trying to read in multiple .xlsx files to R from the same directory. I keep getting the following error.

> "Error in path.expand(file) : argument "file" is missing, with no default"

My code is as follows.

```
require(.xlsx)
Files=list.files(path="I:/Marcs_Discretinization_try_1/Attempt1/Actual     Data", pattern=".xlsx")
sapply(Files, read.xlsx2(sheetIndex=8))
```

The output of object Files looks like this which seemingly does not have the attached path.

```
 [1] "2015-B1-2OR.xlsx"    "2015-B1-OR10-B.xlsx" "2015-B1-OR10.xlsx"   "2015-B1-OR19.xlsx"   "2015-B2-OR19.xlsx"  
 [6] "2015-O1-2OR.xlsx"    "2015-O1-OR10-B.xlsx" "2015-O1-OR10.xlsx"   "2015-O2-2OR.xlsx"    "2015-O2-OR10-B.xlsx"
[11] "2015-O2-OR10.xlsx"   "2015-X1-2OR.xlsx"    "2015-X1-OR10-B.xlsx" "2015-X1-OR10.xlsx"   "2015-X2-2OR.xlsx"   
[16] "2015-X2-OR10-B.xlsx" "2015-X2-OR10.xlsx"
```

Comment: If you want the full path returned, use `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files`

Comment: This feels closer  however the same error is returned:

 `Error in path.expand(file) : argument "file" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Your sapply syntax is wrong, additional arguments to read.xlsx2 come after the name of the function. Try looking at some examples.

Comment: also, your use of `sapply` is incorrect which is the source of the error.  Try `sapply(Files, function(x) read.xlsx2(x, sheetIndex=8)`

Comment: This helped @Jay. The data files are being read in as a single massive dataframe where each row is a vector as opposed to individual dataframes.

Comment: Any idea on how to make them individual dataframes?

Comment: @Dilliplaine33 Many would argue that it would be better to keep them as a list but if you want to assign individual data frames, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11433532/2835261

Comment: Simpler: `sapply(Files, read.xlsx2, sheetIndex=8)`. For your last question, read `help(sapply)` and you may find your answer in `simplify`.

Comment: @r2evans, even closer! simplify=False makes a more useful dataframe. I am now fumbling with this code to generate individual dataframes but am having errors.
 `for (i in 1:length(Files)[1])
{assign(paste0("DF", i))=read.xlsx2(Files[i],sheetIndex=1, header=T)}`


_Error in assign(paste0("DF", i)) = read.xlsx2(Files[i], sheetIndex = 1,  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object_

Comment: Found it!! `for (i in 1:length(Files)[1])
+ {assign(paste0("DF", i), read.xlsx2(Files[i],sheetIndex=1, header=T))}` does the trick. My problem was in the layout of assign.

Comment: Though it may give you something with which you can work, there are several things about that method that are actively discouraged as well as unnecessary. @Jay suggested keeping them in one data.frame, and that may work better if you were to `cbind` a column indicating the different sources. Even without that, I am inferring that you will be doing similar things to each data.frame, so another option would be to use `simplify=FALSE` (which was my point earlier) and keep them unique in a list; that way, you can apply one function to all of them in one fell swoop. Also, why `length(Files)[1]`?

Comment: @r2evans `length(Files)[1]` is an artifact of earlier code where I needed to treat something for each row hence the [1]. That may be redundant here.
You are very correct in your thinking that I will be doing the same thing to each data frame so I have become very intrigued by simplify=FALSE. I have never accessed data in this fashion, how can a function be applied to all of them within themselves?

Answer (score 3):

You want to merge all Excel files in a folder?

```
library(xlsx)
setwd("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/excel_files")
data.files = list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")
data <- lapply(data.files, function(x) read.xlsx(x, sheetIndex = 1))

for (i in data.files) {
    data <- rbind(data, read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use a `lapply` and `bind_rows` usually. Comfortable and fast.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(magittr)
require(readxl)

path <- "I:/project/raw_data"
  
url_xlsx <- list.files(path, pattern = "*.xlsx", recursive = TRUE)
  
read_xlsx_files <- function(x){
   df <- read_xlsx(path = paste(path, x, sep = "/"))
   return(df)
 }
  
df <- lapply(url_xlsx, read_xlsx_files ) %>%
   bind_rows()
```